# How to use different host group for each module in ansible playbook

Tags: ansible

I have two host groups in the ansible host file.

```
[hostGroup1]
host1
host2

[hostGroup2]
host3
host4
```

I have a playbook with two modules, let's say a copy module and a systemd module.

how to make the playbook to run the copy module only for hostGroup1 and systemd module only for hostGroup2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write like this:

```
- name: hostgroup1 tasks
  hosts: hostgroup1
  tasks:
  - debug: var=inventory_hostname

- name: hostgroup2 tasks
  hosts: hostgroup2
  tasks:
  - debug: var=inventory_hostname
```

Output will be:

```
PLAY [hostgroup1 tasks] *********************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [debug var=inventory_hostname] *********************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [host1] => {
    "inventory_hostname": "host1"
}
ok: [host2] => {
    "inventory_hostname": "host2"
}

PLAY [hostgroup2 tasks] *********************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [debug var=inventory_hostname] *********************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [host3] => {
    "inventory_hostname": "host3"
}
ok: [host4] => {
    "inventory_hostname": "host4"
}
```

Comment: That was an example. You can replace the ```debug``` modules with your ```copy``` or ```systemd``` modules as required.

Comment: ```debug``` module simply echoes the value of the variable passed in to it.

Comment: Thank you... additionally, is there any way to run only on the first host of hostgroup?

Comment: You can use the ```run_once``` directive to run the tasks at the first host.
From ansible docs:
```run_once
Boolean that will bypass the host loop, forcing the task to attempt to execute on the first host available and afterwards apply any results and facts to all active hosts in the same batch.
```

Comment: Or you can use the ```when``` condition to run the task for a specific host as ```when: inventory_hostname == host1```

Comment: run_once will work, since i dont know abut host details,,, Thanks a lot.. +1

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use just one play you can write like this:

```
- name: Just 1 play
  hosts: hostgroup1,hostgroup2
  tasks:
  - debug: var=inventory_hostname
    when: 'hostgroup1' in group_names

  - debug: var=inventory_hostname
    when: 'hostgroup2' in group_names
```

`group_name` is a variable that contains all the groups to which each host belongs, then you could run each tasks in differents groups. You could change the module of the first task by `copy` module and the module of the second task by the `systemd` module.